# How to implement different accessibility modifiers when I implement the interface

Tags: c#, inheritance, interface, access-modifiers, interface-implementation

I want to create an interface with property which has different accessibility modifiers in derived classes, like:

```
public interface IPrisoner
{
    string PrisonerName { get; set; }
}

public class Prisoner : IPrisoner
{
    public string PrisonerName { get; private set; }
}
```

but in this case I get an error:

> 'Prisoner' does not implement interface member
>   'IPrisoner.PrisonerName.set'. 'Prisoner.PrisonerName.set' is not
>   public.

How to implement it?

Comment: You could change the interface to only expose the `get`.  But anything in an interface is by default `public`.

Comment: You can't. The interface says it has to be public, so it has to be public. Otherwise what would you expect to happen if someone did `IPrisoner prisoner = new Prisoner(); prisoner.PrisonerName = "Foo";`?

Comment: You can't. The interface requires both get and set. The only alternative is explicit interface implementation of the property.

Comment: If you follow @mikez and implement explicitly, then you could have another `get`-only property of the name `PrisonerName` which simply returns the explicitly implemented property's value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you're in control of the interface definition, and can change it. If that's the case, it's as simple as omitting the setter from the property definition on the interface, like so:

```
public interface IPrisoner
{
    string PrisonerName { get; }
}
```

This will make the interface only provide a getter. When you implement the interface however, you're free to define the setter using any access modifier you want, so as in your question, you can just implement the interface as follows:

```
public class Prisoner : IPrisoner
{
    public string PrisonerName { get; private set; }
}
```

If you define the setter here as public (IE, omit the `private` access modifier), It still won't make it available over the `IPrisoner` interface, only references to the concrete `Prisoner` type will expose it. You can define properties which only have a setter and no getter over an interface in the same way.